# Different way to convert object to array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

When use this code:

`$array=(array)$yourObject;`

The properties of `$yourObject` convert to index an array, but how can convert as one array, these means, the `$yourObject` be one index of `$array` and I `echo $array[0]` for access through object?!

**Another way for question, please see this sample code:**

```
<?php

$var1 = (string) 'a text';
$var2 = (array) array('foo', 'bar');
$var3 = (object) array("foo" => 1, "bar" => 2);

//It's OK.
foreach((array)$var1 as $v) {
    echo $v."<br>";
}

echo "<hr>";

//It's OK.
foreach((array)$var2 as $v) {
    echo $v."<br>";
}

echo "<hr>";

//It's NOT OK. I want through $var3 in output as an array with one index!
foreach((array)$var3 as $v) {
    echo $v."<br>";
}

echo "<hr>";

?>
```

**Other way:**

I want use a variable in foreach but I not sure about type this, I want working foreach without error for any type variable (string, array, object,...)
For example I thinks must I have this sample output for some this types:

Output for $var1:

```
array
  0 => string 'a text' (length=6)
```

Output for $var2:

```
array
  0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  1 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Output for $var3:

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'foo' => int 1
      public 'bar' => int 2
```

And the end I sure the foreach return current result without error.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It's somewhat difficult to understand.

Comment: `//It's NOT OK. I want through $var3 in output as an array with one index!` what does that mean?

Comment: I edited my question again.

Answer (score 2):

You mean to wrap your object inside an array?

```
$array = array($yourObject);
```

As mentioned by mc10, you can use the [new short array syntax as of PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-82):

```
$array = [$yourObject];
```

Comment: Or alternatively, in PHP 5.4 (?), you can use `$array = [ $yourobject ];`.

Comment: Not in PHP no. $array=(array)$yourObject; is corrent

Comment: @popnoodles What? `$array=(array)$yourObject;` is something completely different.

Comment: what he's asking is ambiguous though reading it for the 10th time you might be right.

Comment: no not after figuring you were probably right about what he wants instead.

Comment: yeah, but maybe the $yourobject was a array! so, not ok your code.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. What do you mean?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Even if `$yourobject` was a (badly named) array, this code still produces the expected result as specified by the answerer. If you disagree with this specification, please post the desired one

Comment: @JanDvorak Heh, `"Haven't you heard? Crowdsoucing to stackOverflow is the new trend in basic debugging."` so true :P